# Harmonize If statement with one condition and multiple values

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have this code written to exempt breadcrumb from certain Prestashop 1.7 pages and it works. However, the way the condition - `$page.page_name` - is repeated does not appear okay with me especially if I intend to exempt the breadcrumbs from additional web pages. Currently, the index and order-confirmation pages are exempted and I would be adding more.

```
{if $page.page_name != 'index' && $page.page_name != 'order-confirmation'}
                                {include file='_partials/breadcrumb.tpl'}
                            {/if}
```

Please suggest if there is a better and more precise way to write this code. I tried the code below but it didn't work:

```
{if $page.page_name != 'index, order-confirmation'}
                                {include file='_partials/breadcrumb.tpl'}
                            {/if}
```

Comment: You are looking for `in_array()`. Or `!in_array()` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
{if !in_array($page.page_name, array('index','order-confirmation'), true) }
    {include file='_partials/breadcrumb.tpl'}
{/if}
```

Comment: This worked for me and it looks much cleaner without the repetition. Also, I got an error initially but I figured it out. There is a closing bracket - `)` missing after true.

Comment: yep glad to help you! And good catch for the missed )  :). Accept the answer when you can to help other persons with your same problem @atsngr